# Goomento is not displayed in react theme ScandiPWA Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2.4.4, react

When using a react ScandiPWA theme and goomento page builder and appears an error when switching to my theme in consturcto. Styles does not apear when switching to the react ScandiPWA theme, but appear on standart themes written in php: Magento luma and blank.
Tell me how to solve it. Thanks in regards!
Here are scrinshots:
[image]

[image]

Magento luma works fine:

[image]